# Complexity of this for loop

Tags: java

I am confused as to the run time for a method. The method is given below:

```
    public void remove(List<String> list){
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
             list.remove(0);
        }
```

Can someone please explain to me why this will only run N/2 times rather than N times?

Comment: This will cause a ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: ConcurrentModificationException is only with iterators (e.g. for each)

Comment: @elbuild Not in this case. They are not using an iterator.

Comment: @user2904796 What will the value of size() be for each iteration?

Comment: @user2904796 What don't you tried with a small list, printing the size at each iteration?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looping through and arraylist and removing elements at specified index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313572/looping-through-and-arraylist-and-removing-elements-at-specified-index)

Comment: I am not entirely sure. I assume we are considering the generic case with a list containing n elements, whatever n may be. Doesn't the list.size() stay constant at n if that is the case?

Comment: You're both right sorry. I assumed the for syntax for (String s : list) { ... } which causes the exception. In this case the loop will run.

Comment: @user2904796 It is evaluated every loop cycle. Your array got smaller, so list.size() got smaller. You skip elements: 1st element becomes 0th when you remove 0th element; after that you get to 1st element which is a former 2nd element. You never touch the original 1st element (and so on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in every loop you are removing 0th element, after N/2 iterations, "i" will be N/2 and size of the list will also be N/2. So after that loop will exit.

Note that list size is going down by 1 and "i" is increasing by 1, hence N/2 iterations.

If N is odd, it will be (N/2)+1.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are looping with the list.size() condition. Since you are removing an element at every step, the list.size() will be smaller.

If you want to remove all elements from a list, you can use list.clear()

Answer (score 0):

Actually the loop is executed `M = (N+1)/2` times where `/` is integer division.
Run this test program and you will figure out why the loop is run only `M` times.
Try it also with this line `lst.add("FFF");` commented out.
The key here is that the `list.size()` value changes when you remove elements.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test036 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
        lst.add("AAA");
        lst.add("BBB");
        lst.add("CCC");
        lst.add("DDD");
        lst.add("EEE");
        lst.add("FFF");
        remove(lst);

    }

     public static void remove(List<String> list){
            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                 String str = list.get(0);
                 list.remove(0);
                 System.out.println("Removed: " + str + " i = " + i + " size: " + list.size());
            }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to remove every member of the list, you need to execute the loop the same number of times as the *original* size of the list.

```
    public void remove(List<String> list){
    int numberOfListElements = list.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfListElements; i++)
        list.remove(0);
        }
    }
```